# Where is this spam message sent using the Contact Form plugin?

Tags: craft3, plugin-contactform

I've noticed all of my Contact Form spam has a referrer that matches the form's location. Building a module is out of my comfort zone for now (not really a developer). I am currently using the Honeypot plugin, though, so I have a simple conditional in my contact page which compares the referer to the URL and if it's the same, fills the Honeypot field with a value.

The Honeypot plugin will set the `isSpam` flag to true, which prevents the message from being delivered. Then the form redirects to its default "Thank You" template.

What I want is for this template to display a message that the submission was flagged as spam and not delivered. I can see that `/craft/vendor/craftcms/contact-form/src/Mailer.php` has code that sets a message when `isSpam` is set to `true`:

```
if ($event->isSpam) {
   Craft::warning('Contact form submission suspected to be spam.', __METHOD__);
   return true;
}
```

…but for the life of me I can't find how to access `Craft::warning` or to have it output into a template. Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently not possible without forking the [Contact Form plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form) and changing the logic to do what you're looking for.

There are other form builder/contact form plugins that might have more options when dealing with SPAM you might want to look at as well: https://plugins.craftcms.com/search?q=contact%20form

Comment: Thanks Brad, that's too bad about the spam flag but I'll look into the Form code. I did comb through the other contact plugins but my needs are pretty simple compared to what is out there. :)